# How to transfer money to a bank account overseas from a bank account tied to my phone?

Tags: banking

Suppose I move to another country and open a bank account there, how will I be able to transfer money from my account in another country to this new overseas account when my old account is tied to my phone number? i.e for me to do anything with my account, a pin is sent to my phone number for verification. For transfer will I be able to do this while abroad using roaming charges on the phone number the old acccount is tied to?

Comment: Are you sure that what you describe isn't just two-factor authentication? If so, you could just change it send you an email instead of a text/notification on your phone.

Comment: Welcome new user, I'm sure this question will be useful to many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will I be able to do this while abroad using roaming charges on the phone number the old acccount is tied to

Yes you can. But the overall situation is a real pain in the ass.  Things to watch for:

So say you're originally from, I dunno, New Zealand and you find yourself in Spain.

Two problems

1. Even though you **think your phone will roam**, annoyingly when you are in Spain there may be problems with getting the text, for one reason or another. It always seems to happen.
2. The bank's computer will ***know that you are in Spain***.  As such you very often get yet another security check.  A message will come up saying "You seem to be connecting from a new IP / new area. We will have to verify it is you by ..."

   - They might send an email .. easy enough
   - They might send (yet another) code by SMS .. see point one
   - They may well want you to phone them or similar

This sort of thing is a real PITA.  You have to be careful.

Obligatory anecdote: I had a business account with a Scandinavian bank (Hansapank I think).  One day I walked in to the office and my awesome 5 yr old child was playing with the pin code generator!  Of course after a few tries it locks.  In fact at that time, you absolutely could not get your code fob replaced other than by physically personally visiting the branch. (Dunno if it's the same now.) So I had to fly from Asia to Europe for only that purpose!  :O

*Note* as a commentor says above, sometimes you can turn off the SMS code system. You could do that ahead of time. Depends on your bank. Unfortunately though, I've noticed that when you do that, the "you're overseas!" systems sometimes get more stringent.